# String number Comparison

Tags: php

I have a variable containing time and date:

```
$a = "2018-10-19 19:04:53";
```

Now I need to check if the year is greater than or equal to 2019, then if the month is greater than 01 (January), then the date. I tried using `strpos` but it didn't work.

```
if (strpos($a, 2018>) !== false) {
        echo 'true';
```

Comment: $a = "2019-10-19 19:04:53";
if ( date("Y",strtotime($a)) >= 2019 && date("m",strtotime($a)) > 01)
   {
        echo 'True';
      }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = "2018-10-19 19:04:53";
$year=date("Y",strtotime($a));  // output- 2018
$month=date("m",strtotime($a)); // output- 10
if($year>=2019 && $month>01){

       echo 'your code';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$a=strtotime('2018-10-19 19:04:53');
$b=strtotime('2019-01-31');

if ($b > $a) {
  echo "True";
}
```

Comment: thanx it works  but I choose the first Right Answer. I up voted you but unfortunately I need at least 15 reps to upvote

Answer (score 1):

You can use below PHP code:

```
$a = "2018-10-19 19:04:53";
if (date("Y",strtotime($a)) >= 2018 && date("m",strtotime($a)) > 01) {
    echo 'True';
}
```

Comment: thanx it works  but I choose the first Right Answer. I up voted you but unfortunately I need at least 15 reps to upvote